# Vue.cli modify webpack to NOT embed json file during build?

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm building an app using vue.js cli. The app references an external json file for the data.  After building, I'd like this json file to exist as a stand-alone file to be edited in the future to update the app when needed.  How can I configure the webpack build for vuejs cli to not embed the json file in the app?

In the vue component, I'm doing:

`import json from "~/assets/data.json";`

but maybe I need to change that over to axios or something and just treat it as a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Webpack config, add the file as an [external dependency](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    myDataFileVariable: './assets/data.json'
  }
}
```